# Listening data over TCP/Ip and then Writing data into File as XML

Tags: c#, tcp, stream

Our Client have a dialysis machine which use Ethernet TCP/IP Protocol and data transfer protocol is XML.It automatically connects to the our
computer system by using the configured IP address and port number and sends unsolicited data messages every 60 seconds to our system. Client send data as XML Data Stream. Now I need to store data in XML file.

For above requirement I developed a TCP/IP listener(.exe) as destop app. Below is code:

```
        server = new TcpListener(localAddr, port);
        server.Start();
        while (true)
        {
            string FileName = "NiproMI" + DateTime.Now.ToString().Replace(" ","_") + ".xml";
            NiproEventsLog.WriteLog(FileName);
            NiproEventsLog.WriteLog("Waiting for a connection... ");
            TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
            NiproEventsLog.WriteLog("Connected!");
            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
            string fileContent = sr.ReadToEnd();
            File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(GetAppConfigValues.GetAppConfigValue("XmlFilePath"), FileName), fileContent);
            client.Close();
        }
```

Is this right way or is there is any better way?
kindly help.

Comment: _"Is this right way or is there is any better way?"_ - Well, first of all, I'd expect this to be a (Windows-) Service rather than a desktop app.

Comment: This will also handle only one single machine at a time. Is that on purpose?

Comment: You also should use a "using" block or at least try/finally to gracefully clean up resources in case of an exception.

Comment: BTW: "dialysis machine" - are those information "critical" or just purely informational? (I.e. can a patient actually be harmed if this software fails?)

Comment: @Fidor Currently my focus is on just how to listen data and then store, yes I agree Window Service is far better option. Yes, It will handle one single machine at a time. Yes, I should use Try or using, I used in original code, here it is just snippet. No, No patient will be harmed if any thing fail, These are just informational.

Comment: You keep on appending to the same file.  So as file gets larger the time will also increase.  Also be away that the xml file is not going to be well formed which I think is acceptable for log files.  Normally XML has one root element.  When you store log files you will have an array of elements at root.  You may want to consider creating a StreamWriter and don't close after each message so you are not appending.  Then Flush after each message so the data get put into the file instead of fragments being in the stream.

Comment: _"Window Service is far better option."_ - Of course, for a "proof of concept", where you need to code, try, fail, repeat, a desktop app might make sense to start off with and later make the "production app" a service.

Comment: @jdweng _"You keep on appending to the same file"_ - why do you think so? OP is concating a DateTime.Now into the filename in every iteration.

Comment: @Fildor Now This program needs to handle more than one machine at a time. However this is receiving data from only one machine, How can I handle it?

Comment: I'd make a new question for that. That would be easier.

Comment: @Fildor Kindly share the link of new question.

Comment: I would, if I were you. I did not. :D

Comment: @Fildor https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72990353/receiving-data-only-from-one-machine-instead-of-all-machine-over-tcp-ip