# Receiving Data only from one machine instead of all machine over TCP/IP

Tags: c#, tcp, tcpclient, networkstream

Our Client have a dialysis machine which use Ethernet TCP/IP Protocol and data transfer protocol is XML.It automatically connects to the our computer system by using the configured IP address and port number and sends unsolicited data messages every 60 seconds to our system. Client send data as XML Data Stream. Now I need to store data in XML file.
Below is my code.

Here now problem is, Client is sending data messages from four machines, However my code is capturing data from only one machine, Kindly suggest what I am missing here.

```
namespace NiproMI
{
    class NiproListener
    {
        public static void GetXMLStream()
        {
            TcpListener server = null;
            try
            {
                Int32 port = Int32.Parse(AppConfigValues.GetAppConfigValue("Port"));
                IPAddress localAddr = IPAddress.Parse(AppConfigValues.GetAppConfigValue("IPAddress"));
                server = new TcpListener(localAddr, port);
                server.Start();
                Byte[] bytes = new Byte[256];
                String data = null;
                while (true)
                {
                    TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
                    NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
                    string fileName = "NiproMI_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy--HH-mm-ss-ffff") + ".xml";
                    int i;
                    while ((i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
                    {

                        data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
                        WriteToFile(data, fileName);
                        if (data.Contains("</Rec>"))
                            {
                            MoveInputFile(fileName);
                            fileName = "NiproMI_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy--HH-mm-ss-ffff") + ".xml";
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (SocketException e)
            {
                MIEventLogs.WriteLog("SocketException: {0}" + e);
            }
            finally
            {
                server.Stop();
            }

        }
        public static void WriteToFile(string sMessage, string fileName)
        {
            try {
                DirectoryInfo logdirFile = new DirectoryInfo(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["XmlFilePath"].ToString());
                string filePath = logdirFile.FullName;
                if (File.Exists(Path.Combine(filePath, fileName)))
                {
                    StreamWriter sw = null;
                    //Open File
                    FileStream fs = File.Open(Path.Combine(filePath, fileName), FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
                    // generate a file stream with UTF8 characters          
                    sw = new StreamWriter(fs, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
                    sw.WriteLine(sMessage);
                    sw.Close();
                    sw = null;
                }
                else
                {
                    StreamWriter sw = null;
                    //Open File
                    FileStream fs = new FileStream(Path.Combine(filePath, fileName), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
                    // generate a file stream with UTF8 characters          
                    sw = new StreamWriter(fs, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
                    sw.WriteLine(sMessage);
                    sw.Close();
                    sw = null;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MIEventLogs.WriteLog( e.ToString());
            }
        }
        private static void MoveInputFile(string sFileName)
        {
            string strSourceFullFileName = "";
            string strDestFullFilename = "";
            string movedFromFolder= AppConfigValues.GetAppConfigValue("XmlFilePath");
            string movedToFolder = AppConfigValues.GetAppConfigValue("InputPath");
            System.IO.DirectoryInfo objdestfolder = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(movedToFolder);
            System.IO.DirectoryInfo getsourceFile = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(movedFromFolder);
            string sourcePath = "";
            string DestPath = "";
            try
            {
                sourcePath = getsourceFile.FullName;

                if (sourcePath[sourcePath.Length - 1] != '\\')
                    sourcePath += "\\";

                if (File.Exists(sourcePath + sFileName))
                    strSourceFullFileName = sourcePath + sFileName;

                DestPath = objdestfolder.FullName;
                if (DestPath[DestPath.Length - 1] != '\\')
                    DestPath += "\\";

                strDestFullFilename = DestPath + sFileName;

                if ((File.Exists(strSourceFullFileName) == true) && (objdestfolder.Exists == true))
                {
                    if (File.Exists(strDestFullFilename))
                    {
                        File.Delete(strDestFullFilename);
                    }
                    File.Move(strSourceFullFileName, strDestFullFilename);
                    
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new System.ApplicationException("Invalid destination folder to move retry file.");
                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
               
            }
            finally
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There are a huge number of issues with the above code. Your primary issue: you need to hand off `client` to another thread to process while you continue to listen for more clients. Another issue: you should use `await` and Tasks to improve responsiveness and performance, this alone will help your first problem. Other issues: Need to dispose objects with `using`. Don't assume the TCP stream will return any particular amount of data, therefore it may not contain `</Rec>`, you need to loop until you are sure those characters have been received even in separate buffers. .....

Comment: ....  Consider using `DateTime.UtcNow` if your time zone has DST. Is the data `ASCII` or `UTF8`? You can use `FileMode.OpenOrCreate` and avoid repeating code. Don't swallow exceptions. You need to find a way to break the loop and cancel the application, perhaps use a `CancellationToken`. Suffice to say, I hope you are not doing anything life-critical with this code because it needs a lot of improvement.

Comment: @Charlieface : The </Rec> is fine.   It is in a loop and code will continue to end is found.

Comment: You need to use Async Listener (async server) so you can communicate with multiple client.  The accept method is called once for each connection.  In the Accept method you have to add each new socket to a list so you can return messages.  Normally I get the remote end point for each new socket to uniquely identify each client.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/socket-code-examples

Comment: @Charlieface : AWAIT is wrong in this case!!!.  How does TCP know when end is found.

Comment: @jdweng There is no guarantee that the whole `</Rec>` string will be in the same buffering loop, it might be split. `await` is fine, it will end when `0` bytes are received, which indicates the socket is closed.

Comment: @Charlieface : You are right. The code should be : data += System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to hand off the client to another thread or task while you wait for a new client.

I suggest you change this code to be fully asynchronous, using tasks and `await`. Something like this should work.

```cs
public static Task GetXMLStream(CancellationToken cancel)
{
    Int32 port = Int32.Parse(AppConfigValues.GetAppConfigValue("Port"));
    IPAddress localAddr = IPAddress.Parse(AppConfigValues.GetAppConfigValue("IPAddress"));
    using (var server = new TcpListener(localAddr, port))
    {
        server.Start();
        while (!cancel.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            TcpClient client = await server.AcceptTcpClientAsync(cancel);
            Task.Run(async () => await ProcessClient(client, cancel));
        }
        server.Stop();
    }
}

private static async Task ProcessClient(TcpClient client, CancellationToken cancel)
{
    using (client)
    using (NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream())
    {
        try
        {
            await LoopClientStream(stream, cancel);
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        { //
        }
        catch (SocketException e)
        {
            MIEventLogs.WriteLog("SocketException: {0}" + e);
        }
    }
}
```

Your code that reads the stream and writes it to a file should also be fully asynchronous. I will leave that to you. Make sure you pass the `CancellationToken` to each asynchronous function.

You should also be aware that the stream may not return `</Rec>` in a single read, it may be split over separate reads. You may want to find a better way of tracking the end of each packet of data