# Multiple TcpClients on the server

Tags: c#, server, tcpclient

I am trying to connect and send messages from multiple clients (TcpClient) to the server. Everything works fine for one client, but I can't figure out how to interact with multiple of them.

I tried to create a list of clients and check through the for loop (which include another while loop), but then no more than 1 client can join (in fact, he joins, but the server does not see it). The Server class code is given below. This code receives input in the form of an array of bytes from the client, converts it into a string and writes it to the console. And it only works for one client.

```
IPAddress address = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");

TcpListener server = new(address, 1234);
server.Start();

while (true)
{
    TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
    listConnectedClients.Add(client);

    byte[] bytes = new byte[bufferSize];
    int s;

    while ((s = client.GetStream().Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[s];
        for (int i = 0; i < s; i++)
            buffer[i] = bytes[i];

        string text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer);

        Console.WriteLine($"client: {text}");
    }
}
```

Comment: In general, after you `AcceptTcpClient()`, you pass that client off to another THREAD where it runs that inner infinite loop. This way the main outer loop is now free to accept another client...

Comment: See [Receiving Data only from one machine instead of all machine over TCP/IP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72990353/receiving-data-only-from-one-machine-instead-of-all-machine-over-tcp-ip/72992487#72992487)

Comment: @Idle_Mind thanks! This is probably what I needed.